# Como passar informação de uma página JSP para um Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Preciso passar uma informação de de uma variável String que está em uma página JSP para um Servlet. Por exemplo:

String caminho = "C:\teste.jpg";

Como faço para pegar esta informação no Servlet?

Comment: Imagino q vc envia essa informação via url(get) ou form(post normalmente), é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter o valor de um campo do form ou valor de parâmetro de um query string, utilize o méotodo `getParameter()` do objeto `request`.

url: www.teste.com?parametro=teste

Como obter o valor no servlet:

```
String param = request.getParameter("parametro");
```

Caso o valor seja um inteiro ou outro tipo será necessário uma conversão de tipo, pois o protocolo http trabalha apenas com texto ou seja tudo é uma string.

Comment: Esse valor da String que quro passar para meu servlet não vai ser mandado pelo meu form pois eu determinarei o que será a String e não o usuario, é possivel passar a informação da string sem ser por um form?

Comment: @R.Santos vc pode mandar por form com um campo hidden, isso não vai ficar visivel para o usuário.

Comment: E como seria isso, seria algo assim _hidden=<%=param%>_?

Comment: @R.Santos, `<form action="sua action"> <input type="hidden" name="param" value="C:\teste.jpg" /> </form>`

Comment: Perfeito, deu bem certo. Obrigado pela ajuda