# Submeter formulário html para uma servlet

Tags: servlet

Fiz uma conexão com `mysql` e estou fazendo um `crud` no próprio `java`. Eu quero utilizar `html` e enviar para o java fazer o `crud`. Pelo que li, precisa duma `servlet`. Tentei fazer, mas não consegui. Seguem os códigos:

classe de conexão:

```
package conect_DB;  

import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

public class Conexao {  

    public static java.sql.Connection conexao;  
    private static String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ucsal";  

    public static boolean conectar() {  
    try {  

        Class driverMysql = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, "root", "");  

        if (conexao == null) {  
        return false;  
        }  
    }  

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " on method 'conectar' error");  
    }  

    catch (SQLException e) {  
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }  

    return true;  
    }  

    public static void desconectar() {  
    try {  
        conexao.close();  
    }  

    catch (SQLException e) {  
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }  

    catch (NullPointerException e) {  
        System.out.println("method 'close()' error. Not conection opened");  
    }  
    }  

}
```

`Servlet` (obs formato `.java`. Seria `.jsp`?)

```
package servlets;  

public class Server {  


}
```

A tag do form:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="Server">

//formulario aqui

</form>
```

Como seria esta passagem para a `servlet`? Não sei fazer o `xml`.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como passar informação de uma página JSP para um Servlet](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154366/91) e [O que é um servlet e para que serve?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91620/91)

Comment: @rray♦ este link pode me servir, mas antes de chegar lá, preciso saber de algumas coisas, como: preciso do xml? Seu eu passar a o ome da servlet no form, então eu já posso fazer o crud sem xml? Caso sim, eu posso me servir da quele link. Caso não, preciso estruturar o xml e depois me servir deste link.

Comment: vc usa o servlet 3? a partir dessa versão uma anotação já serve, do contario precisa configurar o web.xml.

Comment: @rray♦ não sei se posso perceber a versão da servlet. No eclipse, se não me engano, tem o new > servlet. Quando eu tentei mandar o form para a servlet, eu criei um arquivo.java. Então não sei como criar servlet.

Comment: Olha essa resposta tenta colocar as anotações http://stackoverflow.com/a/18187372/1342547