# Enviar informações de um JSP para outro via servlet

Tags: java, jsp

Tenho uma pagina para listar todos os projetos. A cada projeto mostrado vai aparecer o botão de editar.

Eu gostaria de enviar as informações do projeto da pagina listar para a pagina de editar via Servlet.

Quando envio dessa forma, no Servlet o Projeto está null, acredito eu devido a nova instancia do Projeto no Servlet.

listar projetos:

```
<div id="list" class="row">
<div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
    <form method="POST" action="ControleProjeto"/>
        <table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome do projeto</th>
                    <th>Nome da empresa</th>
                    <th>Nome do Responsável</th>
                    <th class="actions">Ações</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <%
                for(Projetos p: listaprojetos){
            %>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=p.getID()%></td>
                    <td><%=p.getNome()%></td>
                    <td><%=p.getEmpresa()%></td>
                    <td><%=p.getResponsavel()%></td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <input type="submit" name="acao" value="Editar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <%}%>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
Projetos p = new Projetos();

if("Editar".equals(acao)){
if(p.getID() != 0){
    try{
        int id = p.getID();
        Projetos pj = new ProjetoDAO().get(id);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("editarProjeto.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("projeto", pj);
        rd.forward(request, response);
        return ;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
}
```

DAO:

```
public Projetos get(int id) throws ServletException {
    Projetos p = new Projetos();
    try{
        sql = "SELECT * FROM projeto WHERE idProjeto = ?;";
        con = Connect.conectar();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, id);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            p.setID(rs.getInt("idProjeto"));
            p.setEmpresa(rs.getString("empresa"));
            p.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            p.setResponsavel(rs.getString("responsavel"));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProjetoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }finally {             
        try {
            Connect.fechar();
        } catch (Exception sqlex) {
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: [Como passar informação de uma página JSP para um Servlet](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154366/91)

Comment: Se entendi direito, vc não manda o `id` do projeto  em lugar nunhum para o servlet por isso ele retorna null. Precisa pegar o valor que vem da request e passar para o DAO recuperar todas as informações do projeto.

Comment: rray: Realmente não estou enviando nada para o Servlet, porque os campos são label. Se fosse um textBox eu poderia nomeá-lo como "id" e assim no servlet pegar o id digitado pelo usuário. Mas a intenção não é o usuário digitar o id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Servlet você deve pegar o parametro ID que você não esta enviando do seguinte modo:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

Para enviar coloque um link coloque em qualquer coluna de sua tabela, informando o respectivo ID:

```
<td><a href="/ControleProjeto?id=0">Nome do Projeto</a></td>
```

Troque o id pelo seu Id respectivo da linha, como fez acima:

```
<%=p.getID()%>
```

Acredito que isto resolva seu problema.

Comment: Renato: Dessa forma funcionou.

`<td><a href="/WebService/ControleProjeto?id=<%=p.getID()%>&acao=Editar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Nome do Projeto</a></td>`